# How to unregister a Shared Worker in Firefox

Tags: firefox, service-worker

I have found a shared service worker named "/store/epic-analytics-worker.js" on the "about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox" page, and there's no way to remove it from Firefox. Regular service workers have the "unregister" button, but this shared worker does not have it — only the "inspect" button is available.

I need to delete it because it sends this message to browser console every 4-5 seconds: "No pending requests, not sending any data. Dropped data:  0".

Is there a way to remove it?